# Error in "Fill Nodata in QGIS"

Tags: qgis, nodata, qgis-2.10

I am dealing with landsat ETM+ images after 2003. While filling the line drop outs usiung QGIS Fill Nodata,  I keep getting this error, **ERROR 1: TIFFOpen:7948_0fill_y_work.tif: Permission denied** [image: Error Image here]

What could be the Problem

Answer (score 2):

According to the GDAL Config Options [documentation](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions#CPL_TMPDIR):

> By default, temporary files are written into current working directory.

As you are running the `gdal_fillnodata` comand from QGIS, the working directory is likely the QGIS install directory, so if QGIS was installed with Admin privileges, you will get the "Permission denied" error when the command tries to write a temp file there.

The [`CPLGenerateTempFilename`](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/09e076400dbbf34e135ad75aefeb28ed91bc9ec5/gdal/port/cpl_path.cpp#L955) function that GDAL uses to generate a temp filename respects the `TEMP` and `TMPDIR` environment variables which you could set before starting QGIS, alternatively, edit the `gdal_fillnodata.bat etc...` command in the tool (click the pencil icon) to include a config option - `gdal_fillnodata.bat --config CPL_TMPDIR C:\Temp etc...`.